# /usr/bin/python running script with different version on macOS

Tags: macos, python

I am running macOS High Sierra and found this quirky behavior of system Python.

So `/usr/bin/xattr` is a Python script that prints error message immediately and exits; and `/usr/bin/xattr-2.7` is the one that does real xattr work.

If I run `/usr/bin/xattr` or `xattr` or `/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/xattr`, they will all run `/usr/bin/xattr-2.7` instead of `/usr/bin/xattr`. Note that there is no way that `/usr/bin/xattr` will redirect control to `/usr/bin/xattr-2.7`. It prints error message immediately.

But if I change directory into `/usr/bin` and run `/usr/bin/python ./xattr` or just `./xattr`, they will run the real `/usr/bin/xattr` and print the error message.

So I wonder what magic is involved here. It feels like the Python that comes pre-installed is able to append version number to script before executing the one I specified.

Follow up:

Running Python from different locations will result in different behavior as well

```
bash-3.2$ cd /usr/bin
bash-3.2$ ./python /usr/bin/xattr
bash-3.2$ cp python /tmp
bash-3.2$ cd /tmp
bash-3.2$ ./python /usr/bin/xattr
python version 2.7.10 can't run /usr/bin/xattr.  Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/xattr-2.7 (uses python 2.7)

Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
Mac OS X.
```

I have attached both files here (https://gist.github.com/hotpxl/f16be705ac8b0cc6b7fbfe951cb68c7b)

Comment: If you run `bash` enter `type -a xattr` to find out what would be run when `xattr` is run. It will show alias, function, script and binary program definitions. At the `bash` command line it will be the first of these which will be invoked, but from other environments (eg within scripts) it may be one of the others.

Comment: ```
bash-3.2$ type -a xattr
xattr is /usr/bin/xattr
```
I got this.

Comment: Does `file /usr/bin/xattr` show it as a script or a binary? If it's a script, you may get some idea of what's going on, in particular what the first line is (such as `#!/usr/bin/python`). Check `type -a python` as well and see if `file /usr/bin/python` is a script or a link, and if it uses an absolute or relative path for the target. Note that if `/usr/bin/xattr` has a header line, this will be called, regardless of where `type -a python` indicates.

Comment: It's a Python script. It just prints the error message and there is no way it diverges control to another script. The first line is `#!/usr/bin/python`. And `/usr/bin/python` is a binary.

Comment: I'm really running out of ideas. I wonder if either `xattr` or `python` is cached: type `hash` and see if they're in the list; if so, `hash -r` will remove them. My only other thought is to type `python -V` in each of the locations where you ran your tests. I am testing with Linux, which has similar environments for both `bash` and `python`, and I haven't seen any similar quirks. I have even tried loading your scripts, and `xattr` works as expected; `xattr-2.7` of course doesn't work, even after changing the first line, but the errors tell me when it is invoked, and all seems as expected.

Comment: I have seen Filipe Brandenburger's answer, having concluded that it had to be something like that. Sometimes software tries too hard to be clever. I'm glad you've found your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MacOS, `/usr/bin/python` is not a Python interpreter, but a program called "versioner" which will try to select which version of the Python interpreter to use.

It will also do tricks like looking for a script named with a Python version suffix when running scripts from special locations such as `/usr/bin`.

This is partly documented in the [man page for python in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/python.1.html), although the exact details of looking for scripts with the suffix is not mentioned there.

See also [this blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201312/versioned_python_commands_on_mac.html) which explores the exact same issue you are experiencing and has a more in-depth explanation including inspecting the "versioner" binary looking for special strings.